# Awk - Match Values Between Two Files and Create a New File

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two files that I am trying to compare, and create a final.txt file with data that exists from both of those files.

File1 - column 1 and File2 - columns 2 contain the value that I need to match between the two files.

So essentially, I am trying to -> take column1 from File1, if there is a match in column2 of file2, then write File1Column1, File1Column2 and File2Column1 to a new file called final.txt.

EXAMPLE

File 1

```
1000,Brian
1010,Jason
400,Nick
```

File 2

```
3044 1000
4466 400
1206 1010
```

Final.txt file to look like

```
1000,Brian,3044
1010,Jason,1206
400,Nick,4466
```

I believe I should be able to do this with awk, but for some reason I am really struggling with this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Search [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/join), plenty of similar questions with answers.

Comment: @don_crissti the `join` approach is not quite as straightforward as it might have been since the files have different delimiters. Quite doable, of course, just not all that simple.

Comment: @terdon - the reason I posted the link is that the vast majority of Q there have an answer that uses `awk`. I bet this is a duplicate or almost a duplicate (if it wasn't for the different delimiter which isn't a big deal imo)...

Comment: @don_crissti and I bet you're right, too. I'm just pointing out that this is a slightly more complex case than the average.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$ awk -F"[, ]" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1","$2; next} ($2 in a){print a[$2]","$1}' file1 file2 
1000,Brian,3044
400,Nick,4466
1010,Jason,1206
```

The `-F"[, ]"` sets the field separator to either a space or a comma. `FNR` is the current line number and `NR` the current line number of the current file. The two will be equal only while the 1st file is being read. Therefore, `NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1","$2; next}` will be run only on the lines of the first file and will save the 1st and 2nd fields (with a comma in between) as values in the array `a` whose keys are the 1st fields. Then, when the 2nd file is being read, if the 2nd field is in `a`, we print the value associated with it (the 1st and 2nd fields of the first file) and the 1st field of the second file.

---

That said, there's actually an app for this! This sort of thing is what `join` was made for. Sadly, since your two files are unsorted and have different delimiters, we need some tricks. If your shell supports `<()`, you can do:

```
$ join -t, -1 1 -2 2 <(sort file1) <(sed 's/ /,/g' file2 | sort -t"," -k2) 
1000,Brian,3044
1010,Jason,1206
400,Nick,4466
```

The `join -t, -1 1 -2 2` means use `,` as the delimiter and join on the 1st field of file1 and the 2nd field of file2. The `sed` just replaces spaces with commas so we have the same delimiter in both files. The `sort` does what it says on the bottle: it sorts its input.